# Crystal Report Show "Please Wait While Document is Processed"

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I an working on Windows Form application Using C# and when I want to print Salary Slip on Crystal Report. It shows "Please Wait while document is processing" dialog box and its keep on processing and hang my application. Rest of All Crystal Reports Working Fine accept this single report.
Please Guide me Whats The Problem

Here is my Code

```
string qry = @"SELECT (Select emp_name from employ_tbl where emp_id=SM.emp_id) AS emp_id,Salary,Adv_deduction,Mdcn_deduction,Loan_deduction,Oth_deduction,Total_Absents,'' AS AbsentAmount,SM.Current_Salary,(select sum(amount) from salarybonus where bonusMounth='"
            + month + @"' AND emp_id=SM.emp_id AND name IS NOT NULL ) AS b_amount FROM SalaryManagement_tbl SM WHERE SM.Month='" + month + "' AND SM.emp_id=6";

string connection = cm.constring();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
        ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();


 DataTable ds = new DataTable();
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, con);
        adp.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();
        cryRpt.Load(@"fullpath\PaySlip.rpt");
        cryRpt.SetDataSource(ds);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
```

Comment: use the profiler from SSMS to catch the query that is send to the database. Then run that query in SSMS and see how long it takes. My guess is you have a very slow query

Comment: i also show query

Comment: run that query in SSMS and look how long it takes

Comment: no time taken. immediate execution

Comment: I also tried simple "SELECT * FROM TABLE"

Comment: then there is something wrong in the report itself. I dont use crystal so I cant help you any further

Comment: Ok Brother.. Thanks for quick response

Comment: Always use parameters.  Is month text or a number?  Is bonusMounth how it's spelled in the table?  If you pause the debugger, which line is it stopping on?

Comment: function debug correctly . but data is not displaying . Spellings are same in the table and query.. i write this query on ssms